# how to sort a list by the nth element in v2.3?

Tags: python

This is a simple script I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

file = open('readFile.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
del file

sortedList = sorted(lines, key=lambda lines: lines.split('\t')[-2])

file = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for line in sortedList:
    file.write(line)

file.close()
del file
```

to rewrite a file like this:

```
161788  group_monitor.sgmops    4530    1293840320  1293840152
161789  group_atlas.atlas053    22350   1293840262  1293840152
161790  group_alice.alice017    210     1293840254  1293840159
161791  group_lhcb.pltlhc15     108277  1293949235  1293840159
161792  group_atlas.sgmatlas    35349   1293840251  1293840160
```

(where the last two fields are epoch time) ordered by the next to last field to this:

```
161792  group_atlas.sgmatlas    35349   1293840251  1293840160
161790  group_alice.alice017    210     1293840254  1293840159
161789  group_atlas.atlas053    22350   1293840262  1293840152
161788  group_monitor.sgmops    4530    1293840320  1293840152
161791  group_lhcb.pltlhc15     108277  1293949235  1293840159
```

As you can see, I used `sorted()`, which was introduced in v2.4, how can I rewrite the script for v2.3, so that it does that same thing. 
In addition, I want to convert the epoch time to the human-readable format, so the resultant file looks like this:

```
161792  group_atlas.sgmatlas    35349   01/01/11 00:04:11   01/01/11 00:02:40
161790  group_alice.alice017    210     01/01/11 00:04:14   01/01/11 00:02:39
161789  group_atlas.atlas053    22350   01/01/11 00:04:22   01/01/11 00:02:32
```

I know, this `strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S", gmtime())` can be used to convert the epoch time but I just can't figure out how can I apply that to the script to rewrite the file in that format.

Comments? Advice treasured!

---

**@Mark: Update**

In some cases, the epoch time comes as `3600`, which is to indicate an unfinished business. I wanted to print *aborted* instead of `01/01/1970` for such a line. So, I changed the `format_seconds_since_epoch()` like this:

```
def format_seconds_since_epoch(t):
    if t == 3600:
        return "aborted"
    else:
        return strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",datetime.fromtimestamp(t).timetuple())
```

which solved the problem. Is it the best that can be done in this regard? Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file = open('readFile.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
del file

lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
lines.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x[2], y[2])
lines = [' '.join(line) for line in lines]
```

Comment: A few small things: 1. the OP's files are separated by tabs rather than a single space 2. you need to compare the second last column, not the third column 3. it's probably best to convert the column values to a number before comparing, just in case some of the values are times before September 2001 :)

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your final query, you can create a `datetime` object from a `time_t`-like "seconds since the epoch" value using `datetime.fromtimestamp`, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime

def format_seconds_since_epoch(t):
    return strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",datetime.fromtimestamp(t).timetuple())

print format_seconds_since_epoch(1293840160)
```

So, putting that together with a slightly modified version of [pynator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126237/how-to-sort-a-list-by-the-nth-element-in-v2-3/5126259#5126259), you script might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
import os

def format_seconds_since_epoch(t):
    return strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",datetime.fromtimestamp(t).timetuple())

fin = open('readFile.txt', 'r')
lines = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
del fin

split_lines = [ line.split("\t") for line in lines ]

split_lines.sort( lambda a, b: cmp(int(a[-2]),int(b[-2])) )

fout = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for split_line in split_lines:
    for i in (-2,-1):
        split_line[i] = format_seconds_since_epoch(int(split_line[i]))
    fout.write("\t".join(split_line)+os.linesep)

fout.close()
del fout
```

Note that using `file` as a variable name is a bad idea, since it shadows the built-in `file` type, so I changed them to `fin` and `fout`.  (Even though you are `del`ing the variables afterwards, it's still good style to avoid the name `file`, I think.)

In reply to your further question about the special "3600" value, your solution is fine.  Personally, I would probably keep the `format_seconds_since_epoch` function as it is, so that it doesn't have a surprising special case and is more generally useful.  You could create an additional wrapper function with the special case, or just change the `split_line[i] = format_seconds_since_epoch(int(split_line[i]))` line to:

```
entry = int(split_line[i])
if entry == 3600:
    split_line[i] = "aborted"
else:
    split_line[i] = format_seconds_since_epoch(entry)
```

... however I don't think there's much in the difference.

Incidentally, if this is more than a one-off task, I would see if you can use a later version of Python in the 2 series than 2.3, which is rather old now - they have lots of nice features that help one to write cleaner scripts.

Comment: @mark: thank you very much. I'll test the script in a little while (it takes a bit of time to generate the actual input file) and report back here shortly. Yes, Using `file` as variable name is bad idea, my mistake indeed. thanks for pointing out. Cheers!!

Comment: @mark: It worked really well. Thanks for your quick replay. Cheers!!

Comment: @mark:Well, just a little question: Sometimes, the last field comes out as "3600", which means that particular job didn't finished successful. How can print e.g. "aborted" instead of `01/01/70 02:00:00` for such a line? cheers!!

Comment: @mark: I've solved the "3600" issue modifying the format_seconds_since_epoch() function; updated my original post. Not sure if it's the best way of doing that. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: no problem - I've updated my answer with another suggestion, but what you have looks fine.  (I also changed the indices in the tuple to -2,-1 instead of 3,4 since you said they were always the last two columns.)

Comment: @mark: Thanks Mark, for the update. I already ran into that `3,4` indices issue; I added more fields in the middle and all went out of sync, so made the changes as you suggested. On a side note, using v2.3 is for a very specific purpose. That particular box will get an update in a month time with new version of core middleware (gLite/EGI), which uses python v2.6, so I just didn't bother. Cheers!!